# What is the best way to design getters and setters and why?

Tags: java, oop, getter-setter

I was wondering what is the best way to write getters and setters ?

Should we check for the conditions in getters or should we do it in the setters ?

Which is the standard procedure to do so and why ?

Suppose I have a class Products:(This is just an example, only asking about the approach to design getters and setters)

```
public class Product {
private String productName;

public String getProductName() {
    if (productName != null || !productName.equals("")){
        return productName;
    }else {
        return "Product Name Not found";
    }
}
public void setProductName(String productName) {
    String productName2 = productName;
    if (productName != null || !productName2.equals("")){
        this.productName = productName;
    }else {
        this.productName = "Product Name Not found";
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: This is just an example. I am asking a general question. Should we check for conditions in getters or in setters ?

Comment: And you should certainly detect errors at the earliest possible opportunity. In this case it should be impossible to either create or mutate a `Product` object such that it doesn't have a valid name.

Comment: If you're asking about best practices, I'd tend to say the best practice is to make immutable objects without setters, use static factory methods, and check the invariants in the factory method.

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: This is a general POJO object, so setters will be required

Comment: `setters` and `getters` should not normally contain business logic.

Comment: This test `productName != null || !productName2.equals("")` is not correct. It should be `&&`, not `||`. I'm not sure who you're asking for an example, or an example of what, but everything you've been told so far seems clear to me, including the now-deleted comment about throwing an exception instead of using an invalid name.

Comment: Ideally that is what should be done, there should be no business logic in Pojos. But suppose we need to put some check, should we put it in getter or setter ?

Comment: What part of my first comment don't you understand? Don't just keep repeating yourself.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check conditions in a getter (unless you're lazily initializing). What makes you think it would make sense to do it in the getter?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Why?  The whole point of using setters and getters is for encapsulation.  The setters should restrict you from enter invalid values. Not saying ALL the business logic should be there, but that logic required to prevent the object from been placed into an invalid state should most certainly be there

Comment: @VinceEmigh Setter will never return null but getters will. Even if you forget to set the attribute it will not return null.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did say normally, and assuming that this is a javaBean.

Comment: @ScaryWombat You said *"not normally"*, where I would consider that they should, normally, even for a JavaBean, but that's me

Comment: A setter doesn't normally return a value. That's what the getter is for. If you don't want the getter to return null, assign a value to the variable before others can call the getter (assign in the constructor/field - do not leave as `null`). Then, your setter could make sure other can't set the value to `null`

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes. That is how I do it. Set default values in constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the setter. It's too late in the getter. Catch the error as soon as you can. And *make* it an error, not just an 'I don't know' case: you should never allow an object to get into an invalid state.

```
public class Product {
  private String productName;

  public Product(String productName) {
    setProductName(productName); // for validation
  }

  public String getProductName() {
    return this.productName;
  }

  public void setProductName(String productName) {
    if (productName == null || productName.length() == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("product name cannot be null or empty");
    this.productname = productName;
  }
```

Comment: Yes. Ok. That is something what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

```
public class Product {
  private String productName;

  public Product(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
  }

  public String getProductName() {
    return this.productName;
  }

  public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productname = productName;
  }
```

Rationale:

1. In general, member data should be private (EX: "private String productName")
2. If "outsiders" need to read a member, supply a getter method.
3. If "outsiders" need to modify a member, supply a "setting" method.  It's appropriate to add validation code to your setter.  It's generally good practice to throw an exception if validation fails.
4. In general, if you *can* initialize something in the constructor, you *should*.  More specifically, the purpose of a "constructor" is to establish "[invariant conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant)" for the class.

'Hope that helps!

NOTES:

- If you're writing a Java Bean, you might need a "no args" constructor.  In that case, add an"init()" method to substitute for the constructor I described above.
- It's perfectly appropriate to initialize multiple members at once - either in your constructor, or in a custom "init()".

Comment: I agree with your point three.